# Remove contact from Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

After I have removed and blocked a particular contact from my contact and chat list, when I search with the contact's name in the search option of my Gmail account, it still throws up the contact's email address with options to `start a video chat`, `chat` etc. I do not have the contact in my circle, neither do I have any mails or chats from this contact.

Why this behaviour?

What do I do to remove the contact completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you deleted it from *all* contacts, meaning from *Other contacts* as well. Also, in the chat list, you should have chosen *Block*, not *Never show*.

When you search for it and you find it, the very first item in that list is the box with his/her details (i.e. “it still throws up the contact's email address with options to "start a video chat", "chat" etc.”), right? There, next to the name you should have a small down-arrow — click on it and choose **Edit contact details** (see images below). This should send you to the contact’s details page where you can delete it from the *More* button in the menu.

[image]

[image]

[image]