# How to remove contact from appearing in Gmail search

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, gmail-search

When I am trying to search for an email address in Gmail, let's say starting with 'a', it always shows me a particular email account which was in my contact list a long time ago. Even after deleting the contact and the emails, it still appears in my search for auto-fill. This happens in any browser; so it is not the cache of the browser though I have cleared that as well. I even went to the [Web and App activity](https://history.google.com/history/) and deleted all history, but it didn't help. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Possibly related: [Remove contact from Gmail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/59220/354)

Comment: Thanks. I think I found the reason but I cannot resolve though. The contact is in the folder 'Directory' of my gmail Contacts. The option More when I open the contact in the gmail Directory is not accessible to me. May be this is because this is a gmail alias for a company.